# How to move a Microsoft SQL Server (in docker) container to a new host

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a Microsoft SQL Server instance running (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) on WSL2.

```
version: '3.1' 
services:
  mssql-2019:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
    volumes:
      - 'MSSQL:/var/opt/mssql'
volumes:
  MSSQL:
    external: true
```

I have a new host that I would like to move the instance to. The two hosts can connect to eachother freely

What would be the quickest way to start Microsoft SQL Server on the new host with all data carried over from the old host?

Answer (score 0):

To move your DB to another host you need to copy your volume with data there and launch the same container image.

You got a volumes config on your docker-compose file:

```
- 'MSSQL:/var/opt/mssql'
```

This means that you create a volume named MSSQL and map it to /var/opt/mssql location inside your container.

In your old host:

1. Get the list of volumes

   ```
   docker volume list
   ```
2. Find out the path to your volume's files:

   ```
   docker volume inspect [volume_name]
   ```
3. Copy the docker config to the new host and launch a container once.
   Find the location of a newly created volume on your new host.
   Copy and replace the files from old volume location to the new one